# How to get all active streams from wowza server?

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

I have been trying to set up multiple live streams (up to 30) and make some kind of small video chat website where the users can push streams to the server and other users watch these streams. I use one wowza instance and one created application called live. After reading all tutorials on https://streamtoolbox.com I 'm aware of user authentication, tokens etc. but I still  have no idea:

1. how succesfully logged user  can gahther all active streams from wowza server? I want him to have HTML page returned with the the list of various videos. Should logged user do some kind of query to wowza server for active streams?
2. How wowza distinguish and store all active streams within one aplication?

thanks in advance for putting some light on this subject.

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution, like a custom module?

Comment: @jabal , I have eclipse with wowza plugin installed, but i am still beginner (although I know Java). A programmatic solution, like a custom module should solve my problem?  But Yes, it could be custom module, problem is that how to start, it is really hard to find some tutorials, that cover my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own module that uses the Wowza API to iterate over all the active streams in your application, or even within all applications running in the VHost. This module could possibly be a HTTPProvider that you register so that you can make it listen to a specific URL and return a JSON/XML/HTML representation of the streams in your Wowza server. Your website could possibly do a request to this module and load the data dynamically for rendering the content to the user. This would be my general approach, the API docs and tutorials can give you an idea how to actually start your own module.

Answer (score 4):

If you are more familiar with web programming, you can also look into querying the active incoming streams using the Wowza REST API. Your REST API requests can be wrapped in an HTTP request, and the resulting JSON data returned can be used to populate an HTML page using server-side scripts.

Here's the REST API call to get incoming streams for an application called "live":

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/instances/_definst_
```

The result would be similar to:

```
{
    "serverName": "_defaultServer_",
    "incomingStreams": [{
        "sourceIp": "rtmp://127.0.0.1:28402",
        "isPTZEnabled": false,
        "applicationInstance": "_definst_",
        "name": "myStream",
        "isRecordingSet": false,
        "isStreamManagerStream": false,
        "isPublishedToVOD": false,
        "isConnected": true,
        "ptzPollingInterval": 2000
    }],
    "outgoingStreams": [],
    "recorders": [],
    "streamGroups": [],
    "name": "_definst_"
}
```

Comment: for me querying the REST api is the best way, but I'm not sure to let users to query directly to wowza api due to server performance if these are too many calls, I think the api is for managing wowza and no to serve users, maybe using an app in the middle to cache queries is safer.